# Seperate StatefulWidget from its InheritedWidget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I currently trying to figure out how to create a PageView with multiple custom AppBars on top. I need smooth transitions between the Appbars so I've currently placed them in a stack, on top of the PageView.

In order to call functions in my AppBarStates from my pages in the PageView, my AppBars needs its own InheritedWidget to recieve the AppBars through context like: `CustomAppBar.of(context).foo()`.

Currently AppBars and PageView is in same stack which means they aren't in same widget tree.
Is it possible to create the InhertitedWidgets of the AppBars further up the tree and then link it up to the AppBars created in the stack?

Example:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return CustomAppBarInheritedWidget(
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        PageView(),
        CustomAppBar(),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```